# How to send localhost Blob(Clipboard Image Data) send to other server (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, fetch-api, google-apps-script-api

I want to send Blob(Clipboard Image Data, Client Javascript) to other server (Google Apps Script) for storing in Google Drive.

client and server is not same domain.

I try below code but It's not working.

google apps script side, e.postData parameter is always return undefined.

What should I do? I don't even know whether it's a javascript fetch problem or a server problem.

Must JavaScript blob data be converted as raw texts(String) before sending?

My English is bad,.

please show me answer code.

## in javascript, html // localhost environment because this html, javascript for chrome extension.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", async () => {
          try {
            const permission = await navigator.permissions.query({
              name: "clipboard-read",
            });

            // permission allowed
            if (permission.state === "granted") {
              const dataTransfer = await navigator.clipboard.read();

              // get item from clipboard
              for (const item of dataTransfer) {
                const isImage = item.types.some((type) => type === "image/png");

                if (!isImage) {
                  continue;
                }

                // get Blob from clipboardItem
                const blob = await item.getType("image/png");

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("blobData", blob);

                fetch("my_google_apps_script_url", {
                  method: "POST",
                  body: formData,
                })
                  .then((response) => response.json())
                  .then((data) => {
                    console.log("Response from Google Apps Script:", data);
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error calling Google Apps Script:", error);
                  });
                break;
              }
            } else {
              console.log("not allowed permission.");
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("clipboard read error:", error);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="test">test button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

## in google Apps Script

```
 function doPost(e) {
   try {
       e.postData is null

//     I will get blob from e.postData and store in my google drive.

     return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ success: true }))
       .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
   } catch (error) {
     console.error('Error processing Blob data:', error);


     return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: error.message }))
       .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Try `return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ success: true, postedData: e.postData.contents }))
       .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
   } catch (error) {`

Comment: I mean e.postData parameter is null in doPost(e).
when use  e.postData, Error occurs, nullpoint exception. (Server Side)

Comment: Does `formData` have value when fetch? Also are you seeing the `e.postData `is undefined in Google App Script execution log?

Comment: yes, 

CLIENT SIDE
                const blob = await item.getType("image/png");  

                var formData = new FormData();  
                // blob is not null, blob is alive , I can use console.log(blob)
                formData.append("blobData", blob);

SERVER SIDE
function doPost(e) {
console.log(e.postData) // undefined

in fact, I use file write in log.txt(in google drive) instead of console.log
because It is not working after deploy as webapp.

Imfortant thing is when I send blob is alive(Client Side).
when server receive side blob is dead.

Comment: Send it as a normal array derived from Int8Array. PS: When you reply, use `@` like @Serenity

Comment: @Serenity Thanks! I will try it. you are really kind.

Comment: @Serenity Could I know Int8Array version below Answer Code? (front side, server side code)

I try send Int8Array in javascript, but It(e.postData.contents) is typeof string in server side.

body: Int8ArrayConverted_Variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Success below Way

front Side

```
const blob = await item.getType("image/png");

          let reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (event) {
            let base64EndcodedArr = event.target.result.split(",");
            let metaDataStr = base64EndcodedArr[0];
            let encodedData = base64EndcodedArr[1];

            console.log(event.target.result);

            fetch(
              "my_google_apps_script_url",
              {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  metaData: metaDataStr,
                  data: encodedData,
                }),
              }
            )
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((data) => {
                console.log("Response from Google Apps Script:", data);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error calling Google Apps Script:", error);
              });
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Server Side

```
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    let json = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var data = Utilities.base64Decode(json.data);
    var fileName = Utilities.getUuid() + ".png";
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, 'image/png', fileName);
    var linkUrl = saveBlobImageToDrive(blob);
    // 성공 응답 반환
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ success: true, link : linkUrl }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error processing Blob data:', error);

    // 오류 응답 반환
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: error.message }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

// 클라이언트에서 전송된 Blob 이미지 데이터를 Google 드라이브에 저장하고 파일로 로깅하는 함수
function saveBlobImageToDrive(blobImageData) {
    // Blob 데이터를 Google 드라이브에 저장할 폴더 ID
    var folderId = 'my_folderId'; // 실제 폴더 ID로 변경해야 합니다.

    // Google 드라이브에 저장
    var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blobImageData);

    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
    var shareableLink = file.getUrl() + '/view?usp=sharing';

    return shareableLink;
}
```